# How To Change DataRow Value?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, datarowview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to change DataRow value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885087/unable-to-change-datarow-value)

I have the  `Two-dimensional datarow array` like this

```
Datarow Mydatarow [][] = new Datarow[5][5] ;
```

and initial `Mydatarow` form database ... 
Now I Want to do this code  and change `Mydatarow` value

```
Mydatarow [Index][i].ItemArray[3]= "S";
```

I use This Code to change `Mydatarowvalue` But it dos'nt work

```
Mydatarow [Index][i].BeginEdit();
Mydatarow [Index][i].SetModified();
Mydatarow [Index][i].ItemArray[3]= "S";
Mydatarow [Index][i].EndEdit(); 
Mydatarow [Index][i].AcceptChanges();
```

please help me to change datarow value

Comment: Define "dosn't work"... what happens? and what was your expectation?

Comment: What is `DataRow1`? I see your 2D array is `Mydatarow`.

Comment: it has no error . program end successfully but value no change.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with declaring the array:

```
Datarow Mydatarow [][] = Datarow[5][5] ;
```

should be

```
Datarow[][] Mydatarow = new Datarow[5][];
```

So:

```
Mydatarow[Index][i].ItemArray[3]= "S";//should work fine
```

Comment: Sorry For Bad Writing code ... i edit My question

Comment: @Masoud are you facing any exception? if so what is it?

Comment: No. it word good . but value don't change

Comment: @Masoud the value doesn't change where? in a gird view? if you insert a break point at the line `Mydatarow[Index][i].ItemArray[3]= "S"` and run the project "F5", now when the function that execute that line triggers, the break point will stop at that line, now you should see the previous value of the `ItemArray` at index 3, now press f10 so only this line will be evaluated, you now will see that the value is actually changed..