# Unable to change DataRow value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datarow

I want to change a `Datarow` value. I want to change `DT2[0].ItemArray[3]` I tried this code, but it didn't work.

```
private void Func(DataRow[] DtRowTemp)
{
    DataRow[] DT2 ;
    DT2 = DtRowTemp; // It work and DTRowTemp value has set to DT2

    // above code don't work
    DT2[0].ItemArray[3] = 3;   // Last Value Was 2 and I want to change this value to 3
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the [ItemArray Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx) you get or set the ENTIRE array, not a single value.

Use this to set the fourth item:

```
 DT2[0][3] = 3;
```

Comment: @shf301, Indeed. Thanks, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help this is working for me. However it doesn't seem to be saving the set value I give it, how do I do persist the new value? thanks

Comment: @Samuroid - What do you mean by persist? Save it in a file or database?

Comment: I have actually got it working now, I thought it was resetting back to the previous value but it isn't, thanks though @ErnodeWeerd

Comment: Trying to reference `Item` is an error in Visual Studio, the second syntax isn't just shorter, it's required: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873972/in-c-why-no-item-on-system-data-datarow

Comment: And I just got crazy why the hell its so hard to set a simple value to a cell compared to my `DataGridView`. Thanks for this, very helpful.