# listbox selected item give me " System.Data.DataRowView" , C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have listbox1 - its datasource is a column (productname).

so i have in the listbox a `MultiSelection` option.

and im trying to make a `MessageBox` for all the option i selected and this the code:

```
  foreach (object selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
  {
       MessageBox.Show((selectedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine));
   }
```

the problem is that im getting this value instead`System.Data.DataRowView`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you populate the listbox (ie what is exactly the datasource)?

From your comment I would say a DataView (and wich contains DataRowView...)

So you just need to cast the `SelectedItem` into `DataRowView` in order to get a value from this DataRowView:

```
foreach (object selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
     DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)selectedItem;
     String result = dr["productname"].ToString;
     MessageBox.Show(result + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

The VB.Net  developers that could fall on this post could also be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7873972/2387010).

Comment: im getting this error :
'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: See updated answer, it was a problem of VB C# conversion http://stackoverflow.com/q/7873972/2387010

Answer (score -1):

Try to change with this

```
ListBoxItem lbi ;
String myStr ;

for (int i =0; i <= listbox1.selecteditems.count-1 ; i++)
    {
        lbi = (ListBoxItem)(listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i)); 
        myStr += lbi + Environment.NewLine);            
    }

 MessageBox.Show(myStr);
```

Comment: getting this error :

'selectedItem' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

Comment: Your answer is for ASP.NET webforms, not winforms (there is no ListBoxItem object in Winforms)

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the ordinal value as in:

```
 DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)selectedItem;
 String result = dr[1].ToString;
```