# How to bind DataGridView from Database after selecting value from combox

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, combobox, sqldataadapter

I am making a Windows Form in C#.I have a `DataGridView`, all I need to bind this grid view to database with a where clause and whose value will be equal to combobox selected item.

I have done something like this:

```
      private void combsalesid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmr = DataConnection.GetConnection().CreateCommand();
        cmr.CommandText = "select * from SalesOrder where SalesId = @salesis";
        cmr.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@salesis", combsalesid.SelectedItem.ToString()));
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmr);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        grdsalesorder.DataSource = ds;

        cmr.Dispose();
        DataConnection.CloseConnection();
    }
```

But it's not working.

Comment: grdsalesorder.DataSource = ds.Tables(0); try this code may it is your problem i thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What is the value of `combsalesid.SelectedItem.ToString()`?

  I guess `combsalesid` is bound to a `Datatable`, so
  `Selecteditem.ToString()` returns the container object (a
  `System.Data.DataRowView`).

  If yes, you just need to cast the `SelectedItem` into `DataRowView` in
  order to get a value from this DataRowView.

  Take a look at this post,
  [listbox selected item give me " System.Data.DataRowView" , C# winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778180/listbox-selected-item-give-me-system-data-datarowview-c-sharp-winforms/16778562#16778562).
  It refers to ListBox but it is the same issue.
- Then when you assign a `Dataset` as DataSource for your `DataGridvView`, you need also to set the `DataMember` property which would be the name of the `DataTable`. Another way is to pass the `DataTable` as datasource.

  ```
  grdsalesorder.DataSource = ds.Tables(0);
  ```

Comment: combsalesid is a combobox which is also bind to a database through DataReader