# ListBox SelectedItems to MessageBox

Tags: c#, listbox, messagebox, selecteditem

I have little problem with show string in MessageBox.
I load date from database into ListBox.

Now I want show selecteditem. I have something like this:

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var selectedItem in CategorylistBox.SelectedValue.ToString())
{
    message.AppendLine(selectedItem.ToString());
}
MessageBox.Show(message.ToString());
```

I select "Sci-Fi" movie category, but I get:

http://prnt.sc/dvmfyl

Can someone help me and tell how to display it in one line?

Comment: can you print value of message on command line  and check if message has some content in it ,

Comment: or try listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() may be it will help  Please let me know if it work I will post it as answer

Comment: i have added sample code please check if it work please mark my answer

Comment: @YashveerSingh I try foreach (var selectedItem in KategorialistBox.SelectedItems.ToString()) but I get:
http://prnt.sc/dvmtl8

Comment: The question is where in which event you are doing it ? also is listbox support multiple selection of not . can you please paste complete source code so that I can help.

Comment: @YashveerSingh 
Here is all I get: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_aqF-0bbuILMlQ0V2ZyZENYLWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ok and which function you are trying to get selected items and which listbox ?

Comment: I try it in (private void AddMovieButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e))

ListBox > CategorylistBox

I try:
CategorylistBox.SelectedItems.ToString()
and
CategorylistBox.SelecteValue.ToString()

Comment: check my answer .if you comment all code and just run this code on  inside the button click it will show you all item which you selected in CategorylistBox  . Output will be deisplay on output window please try

Comment: If someone have similar problem here is solution:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778180/listbox-selected-item-give-me-system-data-datarowview-c-sharp-winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778180/listbox-selected-item-give-me-system-data-datarowview-c-sharp-winforms)

Answer (score 0):

On AddMovieClick please comment every thing else and test this one it will show you current items selected .

```
if (CategorylistBox.SelectedItems != null)
{
    foreach (var item in CategorylistBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("current item "+item);
        // CinemaDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter kTyp = new CinemaDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter();
        // kTyp.AddCategoryType((selectedItem), TitleTextBox.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but unfortunately, I do not know how to implement the code.
I'm noobie ;)

Comment: that is not a issue I will help please show me you source code .

Comment: Unfortunately this WindowsFormAplication and Debug.WriteLine  doesn't work.

Comment: ok then show in messagebox or debug it u can see values  when you degug it

Comment: If I use MessageBox.Show("Current item " + item); I get:
http://prntscr.com/dvo0ar
the i click OK and I have next MessageBox with "Current item y"

All letters: System.Data.DataRowView

i check too:

StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var selectedItem in KategorialistBox.SelectedItems)
            {
                message.AppendLine(selectedItem.ToString());

            }
            MessageBox.Show(message.ToString());

http://prntscr.com/dvo1oh

Comment: ok very sttange cant help more  . do u have team viewer installed  i can connect to ur machine nd chk

Comment: OK, thank you. I found something like this and it's work for one select item:
string selected = this.KategorialistBox.GetItemText(this.KategorialistBox.SelectedItem);
            MessageBox.Show(selected);

but I don't know how to display more then one value :/