# DataRow.ItemArray cannot be modified

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to change DataRow value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885087/unable-to-change-datarow-value)

I bound a datatable to a datagrid. Now I would like to change the datatable's value corresponding to the row of the selected cell once a button is clicked. Here is my code:

```
    private void BtnModifyColorBlue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGrid.SelectedCells.Count < 1)
            return;
        DataGridCellInfo dc = dataGrid.SelectedCells.FirstOrDefault();
        DataRowView drv = dc.Item as DataRowView;
        if (drv == null)
            return;
        drv.Row.ItemArray[11] = Brushes.Blue;
    }
```

For some reason, after the assignment, the datatable's value is untouched. Are there any mysterious things happening here? BTW, I can conform that the assignment has been executed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry. I did know ItemArray was the problem. I thought the problems might come from the DataGridCellInfo. So When I search, I emphasis DataGridCellInfo part and that this why I had not found that quesetion.

Comment: For more context on why it does this, you can read the source code here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataRow.cs,386

The accessor for ItemArray creates a new array, so modifying its values doesn't affect values of the items in the DataRow itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't change through the item array, use the syntax below:

```
drv.Row[11] = Brushes.Blue;
```